# batch file to open tabs in a NEW browser window

Tags: windows, batch-file, browser

I need to modify batch file.

I have a batch file that opens many tabs when I click icon from desktop. These tabs are opened in my ALREADY OPENED default browser.

I would like to have a NEW WINDOW open for these tabs.

The batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off
start "webpage name" "http://someurl.com/"
start "webpage name" "http://someurl.com/"
start "webpage name" "http://someurl.com/"
start "webpage name" "http://someurl.com/"
```

What changes do I need to make

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured this out.

The batch file to open a NEW browser window, and then the intended websites:

```
@echo off
"C:\Users\THEUSER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
sleep1
start "webpage name" "http://someurl.com/"
start "webpage name" "http://someurl.com/"
start "webpage name" "http://someurl.com/"
start "webpage name" "http://someurl.com/"
```

It is working for me. The only caveat, is that if we have a set of pages to open when the new browser window starts up, these will be open too.

Solution? Create another batch file to open those intended websites, and use the desktop file icon to open these. THEN change browser's default configuration to not open specific website or home page on start up.

UPDATE After Alvaro commented on the browser not being the default browser:

For me the default browser is Chrome. Then, for you to **set your default browser** to open, the line **"C:\Users\THEUSER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" should be changed to reflect the path of your intended browser**

Comment: This solution won't open sites in the *default browser*, which appeared to be a requisite in the question.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario For me Chrome is my default browser. Instead of choosing the chrome.exe path, you would choose yourdefaultbroser.exe path.

Comment: The solution should be a script to open any url from a batch script in any computer with the default explorer, not with a specific one as how you are posting.

Comment: Had to change the path to the exe ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").  After making that change, this worked well.

Comment: Is there any option to CHECK if the page is already opened in some tab before opening?

Comment: When I open a new window in chrome, I have set it to always open a new empty tab. However with a bat file like this, it's not needed, so is there a way to close it again in bat file?

Answer (score 13):

This is much simpler:

```
start chrome.exe yahoo.com
```

Comment: Nice, you can send a space separated list. This did the job for me (after starting a new Chrome window first).

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
@echo off

SET BROWSER=firefox.exe
SET WAIT_TIME=2
START %BROWSER% -new-window "website"
START %BROWSER% -new-window "website"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
start chrome "google.com"
```

.exe is not required

Answer (score 0):

if all you have to do is to open multiple tabs at the same time in a single chrome window this is all you need

```
@echo off
start chrome "Your URL"
start chrome "Your URL"
start chrome "Your URL"
start chrome "Your URL"
```