# Opening separate web windows using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like a batch file to open *separate* internet windows in order to keep relevant information grouped without having a ton of tabs.

I can open a single internet window doing this:

```
@Echo Off
start chrome.exe
exit
```

I can open two *separate* windows doing this:

```
@Echo Off
start chrome.exe
start chrome.exe
exit
```

However, as soon as I add a web link to either of these, the window will not open. Instead, a new tab is created in whatever window was open first it would seem:

```
@Echo Off
start chrome.exe "www.Yahoo.com"
start chrome.exe "www.Google.com"
Exit
```

These commands will open *separate* windows if there are no URLs, but they will open a new tab for the link if you include the URLs, usually in the first window that is/gets opened...

I just discovered -new-window [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143132/batch-file-to-open-tabs-in-a-new-browser-window).

I will try that and report back.

Comment: Use `start ""` instead of `start`.

Comment: see: 
https://superuser.com/questions/731467/command-line-option-to-open-chrome-in-new-window-and-move-focus

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo Off
start chrome.exe -new-window "www.Yahoo.com"
start chrome.exe -new-window "www.Google.com"
Exit
```

This is what I needed. It opens separate windows for each without adding new tabs to a different window.